# The OpenCL documentation examples are not working, what does CUDAFunctionLoad::cmperr mean?

Tags: opencllink

I just updated to the latest CUDA drivers and the documentation examples stopped working. I'm using the latest Mathematica, OpenCLQ is True and the error is:

```
CUDAFunctionLoad::cmperr: -- Message text not found -- 
        (clang: error: unsupported option '-dumpspecs') >>

CUDAFunctionLoad::cmperr: -- Message text not found -- 
        (clang: error: no input files) >>
```

I'd appreciate any ideas or help on this.

Comment: Yes, CUDAQ is True. The examples were working for me yesterday.

Comment: It stands to reason that "cmperr" stands for "compilation error". `-dumpspecs` is a GCC switch, which it seems odd to require here. What to do about it, though, I don't know (I don't have a CUDA-compatible graphics card). If it was working yesterday, what might have changed since then?

Comment: Perhaps not helpful: Revert to the formerly working drivers?